# allocated variable inaccessible

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm working on a script which means to put a text at the end of a PostScript file before converting it into a pdf file.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // Déclaration des variables

    // Fichier source
    char *source;
    // Extension du fichier source
    char *extension;
    // Fichier de parametre
    char *fichierPar;
    // Numero et Type de folio du fichier
    char *numeroFolio;
    char *typeFolio;

    // Tableaux contenant les types de folio a scanner
    // suivant le numero de folio
    char **t_F000 = NULL;

    // Allocation des espaces mémoires nécessaires aux variables
    source = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(argv[1]));
    fichierPar = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(argv[2]));
    extension = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    typeFolio = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
    numeroFolio = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);

    // Grille de parametre
    // AJUSTER LA TAILLE DU TABLEAU AVEC LE FICHIER DE LOGO.PAR
    // DANS verification.h
    Grille t_Grilles[NBGRILLE];

    // On copie les arguments dans des varibles plus explicites
    strcpy(source, argv[1]);
    strcpy(fichierPar, argv[2]);

    // GetFolio appel getNumeroFolio qui appel getTypeFolio
    // Ces deux fonctions extraient du nom de fichier
    // le numero et le type de folio
    getFolio(source, numeroFolio, typeFolio);

    printf("strlen : %d\n", strlen(numeroFolio));
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("numero : %s\n", numeroFolio);
    fflush(stdout);

    // Lecture du fichier LOGO.PAR et enregistrement en mémoire
    chargerGrilles(fichierPar, t_Grilles);

    printf("bonjour\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    printf("strlen : %d\n", strlen(numeroFolio));
    fflush(stdout);

    printf("numero : %s", numeroFolio);
    fflush(stdout);
```

The work doesn't stop there but I'm blocking on this point.
Here is the code of ChargerGrille();

```
void chargerGrilles(char *fichierPar, Grille t_Grilles[]){
    FILE *fdParam;
    char *ligne;
    Grille *grille;
    int inc = 0;

    grille = malloc(sizeof(Grille));

    ligne = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

    fdParam = fopen(fichierPar, "rb");
    verifierOuverture(fdParam, fichierPar);

    while(fgets(ligne, 100, fdParam)){
        if(verifierCommentaire(ligne) != 0){

            remplirGrille(grille, ligne);
            t_Grilles[inc] = *grille;

            inc++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fdParam);
}

void remplirGrille(Grille *grille, char *ligne){
    char *split;

    // Separation sur les espaces
    split = malloc(strlen(ligne));
    split = strtok(ligne, " ");
    strcpy(grille->nom, split);
    split = NULL;
    free(split);

    split = malloc(strlen(ligne));
    split = strtok(NULL, " ");
    grille->posX = strtof(split, NULL);
    split = NULL;
    free(split);

    split = malloc(strlen(ligne));
    split = strtok(NULL, " ");
    grille->posY = strtof(split, NULL);
    split = NULL;
    free(split);

    split = malloc(strlen(ligne));
    split = strtok(NULL, " ");
    grille->longX = strtof(split, NULL);
    split = NULL;
    free(split);

    split = malloc(strlen(ligne));
    split = strtok(NULL, " ");
    grille->hautY = strtof(split, NULL);
    split = NULL;
    free(split);

    split = malloc(strlen(ligne));
    split = strtok(NULL, " ");
    strcpy(grille->logo, split);
    split = NULL;
    free(split);

    printf("Hello World !\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

There is my declaration of my struct :

```
struct Grille{
    // Nom du tableau
    char nom[4];

    // Position du point inferieur gauche
    long int posX;
    long int posY;

    // Longueur X
    long int longX;
    // HAUTEUR Y
    long int hautY;

    // Nom du fichier logo.jpg
    char logo[50];
};

typedef struct Grille Grille;
```

In gdb i can print "source", "extension", "fichierPar", 'numeroFolio" and "typeFolio" just before the call to chargerGrilles(fichierPar, t_Grilles); after that it won't be accessible.

```
108             chargerGrilles(fichierPar, t_Grilles);
(gdb) print source
$7 = 0x604010 "F290390001_SCH001-2.POS"
(gdb) print numeroFolio
$8 = 0x604090 "001"
(gdb) n
Hello World !
Hello World !
Hello World !
Hello World !
110             printf("bonjour\n");
(gdb) n
bonjour
111             fflush(stdout);
(gdb) print source
$9 = 0x303732 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x303732>
(gdb) print numeroFolio
$10 = 0x53 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x53>
```

If I put a watch on numeroFolio, gdb stop on this line :

```
t_Grilles[inc] = *grille;
```

What happened to the allocated memory ? Why the variables' addresses change ?

---

PS : Do not take care of the many printf/fflush, It's how I try to spot where is the segFault

Comment: I recommend you write your code, comments, and var/names/etc in English instead of your main language, it will be easier to share, maintain, reuse later. Sorry for the unrelated comment though.

Comment: `t_Grilles[inc] = *grille;` --> `memcpy(&t_Grilles[inc], grille, sizeof(Grille));`

Comment: and are you sure that `inc < NBGRILLE`? I guess it isn't and you go out of bounds of array that corrupt other main local scoped varables.

Comment: @TimF This code is not mean to be shared, only in this case for the help.

Comment: @Lps ... I put a warning to update the value NBGRILLE if the file "fichierPar" changed. I didn't update the value. I hate myself. Thanks. Could you create a short answer so I can validate it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is probably caused by accessing `t_Grilles` array out of bounds into `chargerGrilles` function. Accessing it out with `index > NBGRILLE` invokes [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and, in your case, corrupt other main local scoped variables.

You must ensure that the loop `while(fgets(ligne, 100, fdParam))` takes care of `t_Grilles` size.

So a solution can be:

```
 while((fgets(ligne, 100, fdParam)) && (inc <NBGRILLE)) {
    if(verifierCommentaire(ligne) != 0){

        remplirGrille(grille, ligne);
        t_Grilles[inc] = *grille;

        inc++;
    }
}
```

Best, from my point of view, is to add a parameter to function to pass array size.

```
void chargerGrilles(char *fichierPar, Grille t_Grilles[], size_t size)
{
    FILE *fdParam;
    char *ligne;
    Grille *grille;
    size_t inc = 0;

    grille = malloc(sizeof(Grille));

    ligne = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

    if ((grille != NULL) && (ligne != NULL))
    {
       fdParam = fopen(fichierPar, "rb");
       verifierOuverture(fdParam, fichierPar);

       while((fgets(ligne, 100, fdParam)) && (inc < size)){
          if(verifierCommentaire(ligne) != 0){

            remplirGrille(grille, ligne);
            memcpy(&t_Grilles[inc], grille, sizeof(Grille));

            inc++;
          }
       }
    }

    free(ligne);
    free(grille);
    fclose(fdParam);
}
```

and call it by

```
chargerGrilles(fichierPar, t_Grilles, sizeof(t_Grilles)/sizeof(t_Grilles[0]));
```

As you can see I also added check for `malloc`ated variable. You **always have to** check `malloc` return value. Otherwise you can invoke [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Finally you must `free` `malloc`ated memory or you will see memory leaks.

Comment: That `memcpy` is unnecessary. The OP is performing direct structure assignment, which is supported in C. On the other hand, the dynamic allocation of `grille` and `ligne` make little sense in the first place; both are more than reasonable to be simple locals.

Comment: @WhozCraig I didn't emphasize the `memcpy` change because I did it for my clearness. I agree, local variable are more than  enough.